# Best way to get keyword similarity value from a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to do it, and what would be the best metric for what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm looking to get a similarity value between texts, for example:

`Keyword: "why can't dogs eat chocolate"`

Text:
`"Chocolate is toxic to dogs because it contains theobromine and to a lesser extent, caffeine."`

While there's no exact keyword in the text, there's sort of the same meaning.

Currently I'm using fuzzy string matching but don't think that's ideal. (Using Thefuzz module)

```
value = fuzz.token_set_ratio(keyword, text)
```

In a sense I'm simply trying to find if the `"core meaning"` of the keyword can be found in the text, even if it's a huge text.

Comment: Calculating the [Levenshtein distance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/calculate-levenshtein-distance-between-two-strings-in-python) might be an option?

Comment: I think the question here is really broad, because there are many types and there is no one best way to do it. It's more important to study the different similarity metrics to see which one suits you. To also consider how much effort and at what accuracy you will be comfortable with. Read more here >> https://newscatcherapi.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-text-similarity-with-python

Answer (score 0):

In python there is a RapidFuzz library [RapidFuzz](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/). Written in C++ and are faster on larga data.

There is a planty of configurations so You can find most suitable for You.

Here is a [usage](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/index.html)

One example where You can extract most similar query and also doing it with many processors. No need to implement it by self

```
rapidfuzz.process.extract(query, choices, *, scorer=<cyfunction WRatio>, processor=<cyfunction default_process>, limit=5, score_cutoff=None, score_hint=None, **kwargs)
```